# C++ Assignment, strcpy and strlen with character arrays n pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am working on this assignment and have encountered a problem. At one point, I have to ask the user for two input commands to be used later and I want them put in a char array. I then want to put the input they have into char* but I end up with a Segmentation fault

Here is a small part of my code that shows where I'm having problems:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){

char firstAns[80];
char * command1[5];
int ansLen;

//Ask for command
cout << "Please enter your first command(incl. args) or quit: ";
cin >> firstAns;

ansLen = strlen(firstAns);
for(int i=0; i < ansLen; i++){
strcpy(command1[i], firstAns);
}
```

The program that I ran this from compiles just fine but I have narrowed the segmentation fault to this part of the program and could use some help as a novice programmer :)

Comment: I'm guessing `std::string` is out of the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an array of char* called command.  But you haven't allocated any memory for the pointers in the array, or even set them to null.  SO they're random values, pointing to random memory locations.  Strcpy is then overwriting those random locations, causing a seg fault.  You need to allocate memory for those pointers by `command[i]=new char[80]` on all 5 rows first.

Answer (score 0):

`char * command1[5];`

This is an array of `char*`s. However, it is uninitialized - the values can be any value, and as such they point to random, meaningless places in memory.

You then later use the uninitialized `command1[i]` in `strcpy(command1[i], firstAns);`. Essentially, what you have done is taken a random place in memory and tried to copy firstAns to it. No wonder your program crashes!

Before using a pointer, you have to initialize it to some value. If you need storage in memory, use `malloc()` to return storage of the correct size (`sizeof(datatype)*length` +1 if it is a string) and remember to `free()` the pointer returned from it when you're done with it.

Read more: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

(Gabe Sechan's solution is also valid. new and malloc are the C++ and C ways of allocating memory)

Answer (score 0):

Additional Problem is here:

```
  ansLen = strlen(firstAns);
  for(int i=0; i < ansLen; i++){
     strcpy(command1[i], firstAns);
  }
```

`ansLen` is the length of `firstAns`, it may be possible that it is longer than 5. In this case,
if you try to access `command1[i]`, you are going to access memory that out of bounds, results in segfault.

Meanwhile, you are using unitialized `command1` as pointed out by Patashu and Gabe.